# Bind Kendo DropDown within a Kendo Grid based on the value of another Kendo DropDown which is outside the Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid and two Kendo DropDownLists. One is outside the Grid (category dropdown) and other inside the grid (subcategory dropdown).

Now I want to load this Kendo Grid in the below way:

1. On change event of a Category DropDownList which is outside the grid, based on this selected value, SubCategory Dropdown inside the grid is populated and grid is displayed.

Here how can we read the grid dropdown on category dropdown change event. I have json method to get values for the grid dropdown. Is it possible to call this method inside the change event function.

**.Cshtml**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Web.Areas.Models.RegisterModel>()                          
                      .Name("RegisterList")
                      .Columns(columns =>
                       {
                          columns.Bound(p => p.AssetDTId).Visible(false).Width(15);                   
                          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.SubCategoryId, Model.SubCategoryList, "Value", "Text").Title("SubCategory");   
                          //....                           
                          columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(80).Hidden(true);
                      })                          
                      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)
                      .CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Top))
                      .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSizes(false)) //.Pageable(paging => paging.PageSizes(new[] { 10, 20, 30 }))
                      .Sortable()
                      .Selectable()
                      .AutoBind(false)
                      .Navigatable()
                      .Scrollable()
                      .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                      .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                      .Filterable(KendoConfig.FilterConfiguration)
                      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                    .Ajax()
                                                    .Batch(true)
                                                    .PageSize(30)
                                                    .ServerOperation(false)
                                                    .Model(model =>
                                                    {
                                                        model.Id(p => p.Id);
                                                        model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);                                                            
                                                    })


                                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Register").Data("SendParameter"))                  
                       )
                      .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit").DataBound("onDatabound").Save("onValueChange"))

    )

function onCategoryChange() {
    // Need to Read the grid DropDown.                         
}
```

**Model**

```
public List<SelectListItem> SubCategoryList { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //here I want to set default value for grid dropdown since no value selected in category dropdown.

  _model.SubCategoryList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select Any", Value = "-1" });

  return View("CatView", _model);
}

public JsonResult GetSubCategory(int? categoryId)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _Service.GetSubCategory(categoryId.GetValueOrDefault());
            var data = result.SubCategoryList.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.SubCategoryName, Value = s.ddlSubCategoryId.ToString() }).ToList();
            data.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Any", Value = "0" });
            return Json(result.SubCategoryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Also i got an error

> > Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

with the code in the Index() method shown above.

Comment: Either `_model` or `_model.SubCategoryList` is null. Just put a breakpoint in there and debug it!! Also, put your grid code in your question.

Comment: Yes. error like `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Web.dll but was not handled in user code`